# null pointer exception on filling java fx table

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to set items to the

```
@FXML
    private TableView<Price> pricesTable;
```

where the following columns defined:

```
 @FXML
    private TableColumn<Price, Long> priceId;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Price, Good> priceGood;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Price, MeasurementUnit> priceMeasurement_unit;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Price, TypeOfPrice> type_of_price;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Price, Long> price;
```

using such code:

```
private void updatePrices() throws SQLException{
        pricesPane.setCenter(pricesTable);
        pricesTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(pricesService.getPrices()));
        pricesTable.getSortOrder().add(priceId);
    }
```

where `pricesService` is the following:

```
public class PricesServiceImpl implements PricesService {
    private final Dao<Price, Long> pricesDao = DaoFactory.getDao(Price.class);
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(PricesServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public List<Price> getPrices() throws SQLException {
        try {
            List<Price> prices = pricesDao.queryForAll();
            return prices;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.log(Level.DEBUG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    @Override
    public void removePrice(Price price){
        try{
            pricesDao.delete(price);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            log.log(Level.ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void savePrice(Long id, Good good, MeasurementUnit measurementUnit, TypeOfPrice typeOfPrice, Long priceValue){
        Price price = new Price();
        price.setId(id);
        price.setGood(good);
        price.setMeasurementUnit(measurementUnit);
        price.setPrice(priceValue);
        price.setTypeOfPrice(typeOfPrice);
        try {
            pricesDao.create(price);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            log.log(Level.ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

On compilation I'm constantly getting an error caused by: `java.lang.NullPointerException`
on string with `setItems`. I have several tables that gives the same error on their filling. So I cant figure out what is wrong. Maybe the reason of the error is that I'm trying to fill some columns with objects?

**UPD:**
here is prices service init:

```
private PricesService pricesService = ServiceProvider.getService(PricesService.class);
```

serviceProvider is the following:

```
public class ServiceProvider {
    private ServiceProvider() {}
    private static Map<Class<? extends Service>, Service> serviceMap = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        serviceMap.put(AgentsService.class, new AgentsServiceImpl());
        serviceMap.put(GoodsService.class, new GoodsServiceImpl());
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <Type> Type getService(Class<Type> type) {
        return (Type) serviceMap.get(type);
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you initiating the pricesService?

Comment: @UlukBiy Updated question, added pricesService init and service provider code

Comment: Your serviceMap does not contain PricesService.class so, ServiceProvider.getService(PricesService.class) will return null. Then if you try to use this null object you will get NPE.

Comment: @UlukBiy oh, how could I've miss this. thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serviceMap does not contain PricesService.class so, `ServiceProvider.getService(PricesService.class)` will return `null`. Then using this null object will result to `NullPointerException`.